# Set function workspace to base in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, scope, global, workspace

I have a rather bulky program that I've been running as a script from the MATLAB command line. I decided to clean it up a bit with some nested functions (I need to keep everything in one file), but in order for that to work it required me to also make the program itself a function. As a result, the program no longer runs in the base workspace like it did when it was a script. This means I no longer have access to the dozens of useful variables that used to remain after the program runs, which are important for extra calculations and information about the run.

The suggested workarounds I can find are to use `assignin`, `evalin`, define the variables as global, or set the output in the definition of the now function-ized program. None of these solutions appeal to me, however, and I would really like to find a way to force the workspace itself to base. Does any such workaround exist? Or is there any other way to do this that doesn't require me to manually define or label each specific variable I want to get out of the function?

Comment: one workaround would be to run `save('workspace');` at the end of your function. Then after it runs you can run `load('workspace');` from the command line to see all the variables

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to do what I want as far as I can see so far. Thanks Trogdor!

Comment: If you also want the variables to be assigned after an error, try adding `void = onCleanup(@variables2workspace);` at the beginning of your function, where `variables2workspace` can be a function from any of these answers. It is executed when `void` is destroyed, i.e., at the end of the function or any error.

Comment: A note for future readers: it is now possible to have local  functions in a script file. They must be defined at the end of the file, after the script. This was not yet possible when this question was written.

Answer (score 2):

Functions should define clearly input and output variables. Organizing the code differently will be much more difficult to understand and to modify later on. In the end, it will most likely cost you more time to work with an unorthodox style than investing in some restructuring.

If you have a huge number of output variables, I would suggest organizing them in [structure arrays](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), which might be easy to handle as output variables.

The only untidy workaround I can imagine would use whos, assignin and eval:

```
function your_function()
   x = 'hello' ;
   y = 'world' ;

   variables = whos ;
   for k=1:length(variables)
      assignin('base',variables(k).name,eval(variables(k).name))
   end
end
```

But I doubt that this will help with the aim to clean up your program. As mentioned above I suggest ordering things manually in structures:

```
function out = your_function()
   x = 'hello' ;
   y = 'world' ;

   out.x = x ;
   out.y = y ;
 end
```

Comment: Ahhh `eval`, pleas don't!

Comment: Could I get an explanation on why the `eval` method is no good? It appears to be the method with the least amount of work involved on my part at first glance.

Comment: `eval` is evaluated in runtime. There are a lot of reasons why this is bad. For examlpe compiler cannot find errors.

Comment: Great answer! I have to run my scripts as functions, because I need sub-functions (and that's not possible with scripts). But when the function ends, all variables go out of scope and vanish. With your solution, I can run my function-wrapped scripts like scripts again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the function you would like to define are simple and have a single output, one option is to use [anonymous functions](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Another option is to store all the variable you would like to use afterwards in a `struct` and have your big function return this `struct` as an output.

```
function AllVariables = GlobalFunction(varargin);
% bunch of stuff

AllVariables= struct('Variable1', Variable1, 'Variable2', Variable2, …);
end
```